# C++ - return value used in another function

Tags: c++

I have a problem with using return value from other function. Here are some details:

Class1.cpp :

```
Double Class1::SetValue (double value2)
{
    // method code
    Return value_set;
}
```

Class2.cpp:

```
Void Class2::CountValue(double a)
{
    Class1 *object1;
    Double value_received= object1->SetValue(object1->value2)
    // do something with value_received
}
```

The problem is that I need to use value_set from SetValue in CountValue in Class2. The code above is giving me error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x6462696c in xxx.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: `object1` is not a valid pointer 99,99%.

Comment: `object1` appears to be uninitialized.

Comment: Is this code your actual code or just an example?

Comment: you've got a strange C++ compiler if `Return` and `Void` compile...

Comment: You should provide a better example code. The current one doesn't really give a good idea of the overall problem and is far from compiling.

Comment: You're also attempting to use object1->value2 where value2 is just a local object (method parameter) and is not a member of Class1 at all. Even if object1 was actually created. And value_set does not exist. I guess your code is pseudocode...

Comment: @codah OP is getting runtime exception, so this code must compile

Comment: @marcin_i true Class1 could have a member value2; bottom line is, he should supply actual code because the above is not self contained, compilable, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In your `SetValue` call, you're passing a parameter of `object1->value2`. But you haven't set the pointer `object1` yet, it's still uninitialized. That's undefined behavior. You're lucky it crashed or you might have had a much harder time finding it.

Comment: I wonder how is the chance of calling a method on an uninitialized pointer. I think it's pretty normal to crash. Lucky would be not crashing =D

Comment: @luk32, yes crashing is the most likely outcome but it's not guaranteed. That's why I say you were lucky - it's extremely unlikely that it would have worked the way you wanted, and also unlikely that it would be the same each time you ran it.

Comment: Of course, but I found it funny when you said, that there is any luck in crashing while trying to access and run basically random code. It is expected. Probably not crashing/hanging is less likely than winning a lottery or something. Of course it is not guaranteed, but it's not lucky in this case. It is obvious it will not do what is expected and most likely to crash by a large margin. But I guess its matter of personal taste. We can call ourselves lucky not dying after each day. Even though it seems normal.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues.  There should be no issues with initializing a variable with the return value to some function.  We do this all the time, even when you don't normally see the typical function calls like the arithmetic operators or bitwise operators.

With your function

```
double Class1::SetValue(double value2)
{
  //generally you are setting some variable that is a part of Class1
  this->value = value2;

  //if you are returning something you might want to have some error code 
  //just in case something went wrong, but it looks like you are just
  //returning the number that you are sending in as a parameter.

  return value2;  
}
```

I'm not sure what is going on in your next function but we can dissect it.

```
void Class2::CountValue(double a)
{
    Class1 *object1;//this is a pointer to an object, not an instance of an object

    //                       object1 is not initialized so you cannot
    //                       use object1->value2 even if it is set in
    //                       your default constructor

    double value_received = object1->SetValue(object1->value2);
    // do something with value_received
}
```

In order for your code to work you might want to alter it to

```
void Class2::CountValue(double a)
{
  Class1 object1;//not a pointer to Class1 anymore

  // This will work if object1.value2 is set in the default constructor

  double value_received = object1.SetValue(object1.value2);
  // do something with value_received
}
```

or if you are trying to set both value_recieved and object1.value2 we could do

```
void Class2::CountValue(double a)
{
  Class1 object1;//not a pointer to Class1 anymore

  double value_received = object1.SetValue(12.2);
  // do something with value_received
}
```